# Accessibility of outside variable within a promise in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q, spookyjs

Can someone explain me why this don´t work:

```
var outsideVar = 15;
myFunc.doSomething().then(function() {
  console.log("outsideVar: " + outsideVar);
}).fail(function(err) {
  console.log("error: ", err);
});
```

the output is error: undefined or outsideVar: undefined (depends if outsideVar is a variable or property of an object.

An outside variable should be accessible from inside the function or i´m wrong?

EDIT: I´m using this construction with spookyjs and it seems there is an issue with objects containing very long strings.

Comment: The code snippet looks ok. Can you provide more info?

Comment: It works for me after replacing `myFunc.doSomething()` with `Promise.resolve()` and `.fail()` with `.catch()`.

Comment: You want `.catch` and not `.fail`?

Comment: Oh yes, there is no `fail` method in the Promise prototype. You should use `catch` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Promise_prototype

Comment: What  do you mean by "*depends if outsideVar is a variable or property*"? Also, if it logs `error: undefined` then this means that `doSomething` rejects the promise with a non-descriptive thing.

Answer (score 1):

In NodeJS, you would use a function for the error. Like so:

```
myPromise.then(function() {
  // callback, executed on successful promise resolution
}, function() {
  // errback, executed on rejection
}, function() {
  // progressback, executed if the promise has progress to report
});
```

.fail() isn't a recognizable function in node, unless you have defined the .fail() function explicitly. The .fail() is throwing the undefined error. .fail() in nodejs is used for building unit tests, not promises. https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html

Otherwise, written properly, the closure should work. This is typical closure syntax. See [Is promise a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471826/is-promise-a-closure) for more details for promises with closures.

*EDIT* You could also use .catch() instead of an explicit error function.

Comment: In NodeJS, you surely wouldn't use `$.when`

Comment: modified for clarity in specific node syntax.

Comment: Hi Bryan, sorry i should have been more precise, i´m using q and there is a fail function: https://github.com/kriskowal/q